# My contact form is not being responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive

The contact form on my site is not being responsive.

This is what is I have tried to make it responsive. But, its not working.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 767px) {
               .wpcf7-email,
               .wpcf7-text,.wpcf7-tel, .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-select,.wpcf7-form option, .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-textarea {
                 max-width: 100%;
                 padding: 10px 1px !important;
                background:#c42a91;
                color:#fff;
               }
                .slotholder{
               width: 100%
               position: relative;}  

                    .project_inner{
                  color: #fff;
                  }

                  .cmsms_project_header.entry-header > h4 > a{
                  color: #fff;
                  }

    }
```

Please help me out.

This is my site http://mylittlewhitelies.com/
The contact form is on the bottom.

password: MediaCentralPassword

Comment: When I look at your website it seems responsive. Can you explain more what type of behaviour you expect that isn't happening right now?

Comment: @Andre Thanks for replying. Well, I want the contact form to be responsive, the slider as well.

Comment: The site seems responsive but the form isn't. Are you sure the input fields have no fixed width and the classes are the right names?

Comment: The id`two-column` has a fixed with of 600px

Comment: @Interactive that seems to be it. Can you create an answer for `two-column` with a width of 100% instead of 600px?

Comment: Also, @NaumanTanwir I think you mean `(max-width : 767px )` instead of `min-width`, because right now this code is only called whenever the viewport size is bigger than 767 pixels.

Comment: @Interactive what do I do with the "two-column width of 600px" ??

Comment: @Andre thanks but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#two-column {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

To your css, outside of the `@media` tag. I suggest doing it on the bottom of your css file to be sure nothing overwrites it.

Comment: inside @media tag ?

Comment: @NaumanTanwir see my updated answer :)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3mm1cvbdmekwb61/Screenshot_2015-11-03-13-08-24.png?dl=0

This is what I am getting right now

Comment: Yes, you have to do some additional changes that pads the input fields to the right, but it *is* responsive now.

You can also change `@media only screen` to `@media all`.

Comment: This is because the width of your fields are to big. I saw a `size="40"` in one of them. Take a look at that. Everything should be scalable...

Comment: @Andre I think you need to overwrite the #two-column width value because it allready exists. so `width:100% !important;`

Comment: @Interactive correct, updated the answer.

Comment: thanks guys, 
but, actually I want its width to be 100% on mobile and even I did 

#two-column {
    width: 100% ;
} but due to some reason its not taking affect.